# how to switch/control syntax highlighting in eclipse flexibly?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I have a file with extension .xml.

But it doesn't necessarily contain XML. It may also contain HTML and JavaScript. Now I would like to either have Eclipse decide inteligently/heuristically which syntax highlighting would be appropriate or to switch it myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: not possible. use PHPStorm instead :)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse associates files with an editor. You can let eclipse decide which editor to use (e.g. defaults per file extension) or select the editor by yourself. I guess you might already know that or have at least experienced it.

Syntax highlighting isn't always set seperately but instead part of some editor (together with stuff like keyboard shortcuts). So what you are going to need is an editor that behaves the way you want it to. I do not know if there is an editor like this available but one options is writing an eclipse plug-in and implementing such an editor.

Fortunately there are great editors for each of XML, javascript, HTML, etc that are all open source. I guess you might be able to use some of their code. Ideally as a client of their API / Objects or if it won't work out just by reusing code.